# JPA+Hibernate4.1.6+Spring3.1.2+MySQL persist() not making entry in DB

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm able to retrieve data, update data but persist not making an entry into DB. I guess I'm missing something basic here.

**EDIT:**Jsut found this, calling EntityManager.merge() also doens't update the database. If an update query is provided then the values are being updated in the database.

```
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect"
    scope="singleton" />
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:showSql="true" p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.${DIALECT}"
    scope="singleton" />
<bean id="jpaEntityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="rbtDataSource" p:jpaDialect-ref="jpaDialect"
    p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
    p:packagesToScan="com.onmobile.apps.ringbacktones.service.db.bean"
    scope="singleton" />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
    p:entityManagerFactory-ref="jpaEntityManagerFactory" scope="singleton" />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<!-- This automatically registers all Spring standard post-processors for 
    annotation-based configuration -->
<context:annotation-config />

<bean id="rbtDao" class="com.onmobile.apps.ringbacktones.service.db.dao.RBTDao"
    abstract="true" p:dbManager-ref="dbManager"></bean>
<bean id="categoryDao"
    class="com.onmobile.apps.ringbacktones.service.db.dao.impl.RBTCategoryDaoImpl"
    parent="rbtDao"></bean>
```

Following is the java code for the class rbtDao

```
@Repository
public abstract class RBTDao<T extends RBTDto> {

@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

protected void save(T dtoBean) {
    getEntityManager().persist(dtoBean);
}
}
```

Following is the java code for categoryDao class

```
@Repository
public class RBTCategoryDaoImpl extends RBTDao<Category> {
@Transactional
public void createCategory(Category category) {
    save(category);
}
```

Category is the bean class that has to be persisted.

Thanks in advance for Help.

Comment: what do you your logs say ?

Comment: There is no exception in logs, no insert query even

Comment: turn on all your loggin to the max, tell us what it says at app startup - is it deployign correctly ? Put show sql on, what does that say ? Spring etc do not fail silently.

Comment: Can you tell me how could I share logs with you. I don't see any error with the logs

Comment: I have attached log here http://www.4shared.com/file/Rt38zjVM/sreekar-rbt-db.html

Comment: how do you perform the `update` that does work? Is it also in `@Transactional`? Please show the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your transaction handling is excessive and a bit suspect. To begin with, one @Transactional annotation at the appropriate point in the call-stack is enough. Also, you neither need nor should do explicit begin()/commit() operations when you are using Springs annotation-driven transaction scheme. Also, doing commit() before flush() the way you do, I'm not even sure what that would do, but it's not right.

My suggestion

- Remove **all** @Transactional annotations except the one on your `createCategory()` method
- Remove the explicit `begin()` and `commit()` operations

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply. I tried with your suggestions, but no progress :(